# Can I use sharing?

Tags: macos, itunes, appletv, home-sharing

Can I use "Share my library on my local network" ?
I have my library in a shared folder on my iMac, this is to stop having to have the same music stored twice so my other half can use iTunes as well as me. 
I was told not to turn this on when helped by apple phone desk when setting this up, but that was quite a long time and updates ago now.
I would like to airplay my music to an ATV.

Using iTunes 11.3.1 and Mountain Lion.

Comment: Not sure what is holding you back to use Airplay.

Comment: I was told by apple when setting up "Not To" turn on home sharing with library in shared folder!

Comment: Do you remember what they said why not.

Comment: No just remembered that I was told not to several times during setup.

Answer (score 1):

[Home Sharing](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3819) is a feature that became available in iTunes version 9.

Home Sharing makes it easy to connect to the other iTunes libraries in your home network so you can stream and share--actually copy--music, movies, TV shows, apps, and ringtones.

You can set it up in iTunes:

[image: home sharing]

**NOTE:**

You might want to do this in iTunes preferences:

To prevent iPods, iPhones, and iPads from syncing automatically!

Prevent devices from automatically syncing with this iTunes library when a device is connected.

To sync a device, click the Sync button when the device is connected.

Comment: Thanks for that , but not quite what I was asking!

Comment: Why would Apple make the "Home sharing" and then tell users not to use it?. What they probably told you is to disable the "automatic syncing".

Comment: No they VERY clearly told me not to use home sharing, still lots of time passed now moved on a system up date or 3....